# Bad Request - Request Too Long HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long

Tags: firefox, cookies

Some of my users are getting the following error sometimes when they request some of the pages of my site: 
Bad Request - Request Too Long HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long

It seems to happen only in Firefox.

Deleting the users cookies does help.

What I don't understand is the following: I thought that cookies are appended to every request. Why is it that only one or two of my pages show this error and most do never?

It is also not dependent on the server page. If the user requests
http://example.com/user/Myname
he might get the error. 
If he just changes the capitalization of the URL it works again (like http://example.com/user/myname). (I am running IIS which does not care too much about capitalization).

For the browser the two URLs are different, for the server they aren't.

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It seems that there were too many cookies after all. I made sure that there were not so many and it is working now.

Comment: This just happened to me with Ubuntu & Firefox accessing Office365 after the last update. Worked on other computers not my office one. Cleared the Office365 &  microsoftonline.com cookies and I am back in!

Answer (score 25):

Some of our users also ran into this same exception on IE 8 for some our our intranet sites hosted in IIS. The issue turned out to be related to using Kerberos authentication where a user belongs to many active directory groups.

We found solutions from the following Microsoft Support Articles:

- [HTTP 400 - Bad Request (Request Header too long)" error in Internet Information Services (IIS)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020943)
- [Problems with Kerberos authentication when a user belongs to many groups](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327825)

The fix for us was to set the following registry keys with increased values and/or create them if they didn't exist:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\MaxFieldLength DWORD (32bit) - assigned value data 32000 (Decimal)
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\MaxRequestBytes DWORD (32bit) - assigned value data 8777216 (Decimal)

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters] "MaxFieldLength"=dword:00007d00 "MaxRequestBytes"=dword:0085ee00

Comment: You need to restart the PC for registry entries to take effect.

Answer (score 12):

**Solution 1**

delete all domain cookie from your browser

In Firefox 53

1. Alt -> Tools -> **Page Info**
2. Security
3. View Cookies
4. Remove All

[image]

In Chrome 
check [this superuser solution](https://superuser.com/a/548097/57836)
[image]

**Solution 2**

1. Install **Web Developer** extension ( [Firefox](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/download/firefox/) ,[Chrome](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/download/chrome/) , [Opera](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/download/opera/))
2. go to cookies tab -> Delete **Domain Cookies** like below screenshot

[image]

**Solution 3**

- use incognito mode and see if it works for you

**More details:**

I had the same problem in Chrome and using a list from SharePoint.

after diagnosing with Chrome developer dashboard's network tab. I checked the headers and find the **large cookie** starting with the name **WSS_exp** and  removing all of them from **chrome cookie manager** resolved my problem

Comment: The first solution is for chrome. The OP asked an answer for Firefox

Comment: @Hybris95, I have not noticed that. It is fixed now

Answer (score 9):

The problem is due to a cookie that has become corrupted.  The easy solution is to delete all your cookies but here is the best way to solve that specific issue, I have created a customized guide for Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer. See here : http://timourrashed.com/how-to-fix-the-400-bad-request-error-message-from-a-website/

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for this error stems from the user being in too many active directory groups.  More modern SSRS versions do not have this problem.

It appears that the list of AD groups get passed in along in an HTTP header.  Older versions of SQL Server Reporting Services have a header size limitation.  So if a user is in a excessive number of groups, the easiest fix will be to remove unneeded groups.

If removing groups is not an option, you should be able to edit the web.config file and increase the limit.  You can see how to do that here...
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4688/resolving-the-maximum-request-length-exceeded-exception-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only in the case of using the browser Local Storage to store users' data.

Because the Local Storage has a limit of 5MB per domain, it's never cleared on its own, and there is no expiry date to remove data. When the local storage reaches the 5MB limit then starts storing data as cookies. Later, when the size of cookies reaches 1MB, the browser shows the 400 error (the size of the request headers is too long).

In this case, it is better to clear the unnecessary data from the local storage after using them.

Answer (score -1):

I used **ViewData** instead of **TempData**, and issue solved.

Answer (score -1):

This happens only in Firefox and happens with some regularity. It is therefore not a "cookie problem" but rather a crappy application problem. Stop using Firefox and this problem goes away. Keep using Firefox and every so often you'll get this problem and have to fix it over and over again.