# How to solve "Request Too Long" on a localhost using IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, openid-connect, iis-express

I have a website written using C# on the top of ASP.NET MVC 5 framework. I used `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` project to enable OpenID authentication on my website.

When the I click on "OpenIDConnect" to login using the OpenID server, the authentication works. But when the user is redirected to the `~/` page, I get HTTP Error 400.

> `Bad Request - Request Too Long` HTTP Error 400. The size of the request
> headers is too long.

The issue seems to happens due to having too many claims. Large amount of claims cause the cookie to be large in size.

In my project I have added the following in the `Web.config`

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxQueryStringLength="20000" maxRequestLength="100000000" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" maxQueryString="20000" maxUrl="20000">
      </requestLimits>
      <hiddenSegments>
      </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Still get the `ERROR HTTP 400`. How can I fix this issue?

The **Build Action** is set to `Content` for the `Web.config` file.

[image]

Is there a setting specific to the length of the cookies? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You might find some relief from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112367/size-of-the-request-headers-is-too-long -- some upvoted answers involve clearing duplicated cookies.

Comment: you can reduce the size of the cookies by adding a session store, see this page about the session store https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/using-auth-cookies-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Please try clearing your browser cache completely, and clearing your browser cookies, restarting your browser and trying again.